# Using SVN for Private Github Repo

Tags: git, svn, github

I am trying to set up private repos on Github for my projects. I have my master and branches from my local SVN repo moved into the Github repo. When I try to checkout to a folder for the new Github repo, however, I get an error stating that it can't be found.  Here's my connection endpoint:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>.git
```

When I attempt the checkout, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL  
Error:  'https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>.git'  
Error: '/<username>/<repo-name>.git' path not found
```

I've been able to check out Github repos, including private ones, using this exact same method. I've never created my own though, so I figure there's a configuration setting I'm missing.

Comment: Why do you think `https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>.git` is your repo-URL?! There did you got it?

Comment: Because that's what was provided to me when I selected the clone button. Obviously I have cleaned the path name, I didn't include my actual username or repo name in this post.

Comment: Show output of verbose http-repo, try ssh-repo

Comment: I am using Tortoise SVN to communicate with my repos. I do this with public repos on Github all the time, as well as private ones, so this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a Git repo for a work project a while back and the username and password were saved. Apparently SVN stores login credentials at the domain level, therefore when I started using my own private Git repo it caused a conflict since the credentials don't match. I cleared the stored credentials for github,com and entered my new private repo credentials and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

According to [GitHub's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/), its Subversion URLs look like `https://github.com/user/repo`. Try removing `.git` from the end of your URL and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was hoping this would work but sadly I still get the same error.

Comment: @BrandonParker, upon further examination it looks like it should work with the `.git` part anyway. If you use `git clone` instead of `svn checkout` with the same URL, does it work?